# RxJS ids From Type String To Type Number

Tags: types, rxjs, observable

I want my ids as numbers not strings so I changed the type:string parts to type:number following thru some online tutorial but it's not rendering in ng-server even after changing all string parts to numbers, e.g

```
  getJobIds(): Observable<number[] | any> {
    return of(JOBS.map(job => job.id));
  }
```

from

```
  getJobIds(): Observable<string[] | any> {
    return of(JOBS.map(job => job.id));
  }
```

A N D

```
export class JobDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  job: Job;
  jobIds: number[];
  prev: number;
  next: number;

  constructor(
    private jobservice: JobService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.jobservice.getJobIds().subscribe(jobIds => this.jobIds = jobIds);
    this.route.params.pipe(switchMap((params: Params) => this.jobservice.getJob(params['id'])))
    .subscribe(job => { this.job = job; this.setPrevNext(job.id); });
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }

  setPrevNext(jobId: number) {
    const index = this.jobIds.indexOf(jobId);
    this.prev = this.jobIds[(this.jobIds.length + index - 1) % this.jobIds.length];
    this.next = this.jobIds[(this.jobIds.length + index + 1) % this.jobIds.length];
  }

}
```

P L E A S E    N O T E
All the number words in this code are originally string in the online tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You have changed the expected  of observable but it wont affect anything until it emits the type of JOB id type.  if that type is string you also need to :

```
getJobIds(): Observable<number[] | any> {
    return of(JOBS.map(job => parseInt(job.id)));
  }
```

I'm assuming that ids are integers

Answer (score 0):

[Params](https://angular.io/api/router/Params) returns a string so you would need to cast the value from that as a number

`params['id]` would become `Number(params['id'])`

Comment: You nailed it genius

Answer (score 0):

Ich believe the online tutorial does something like this:

```
getJobIds(): Observable<number[] | any> {
    return of(JOBS.map(job => +job.id));
  }
```

The `+` sign forces a number here.